# Bash simple process respawning daemon

Tags: bash, daemon

Here is a script called `simpled.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

# if top is terminated i want it re-spawn
while :; do
    top & tpid=$!
    wait $tpid
done  &

# i want $$ to keep running after session is closed
disown -h
```

When simpled.sh is run and its terminal reopened, I see that its process has survived `SIGHUP`.

```
logan@logan-VirtualBox-mint:~$ ps -ef | grep [s]imple
logan      25223       1  8 19:20 ?        00:00:01 /bin/bash ./simpled.sh
```

But output i get is `top: failed tty get` over and over.

Here `top` is just a program i chose to see if *respawning* works.

Can you help me fix the code so that `$$` remain running after session has closed (if my code is bad), and `top` to respawn if terminated? You could suggest a different program to test than `top` if more suitable.

Comment: Lookup `screen`

Comment: i already know about screen and tmux. i'm in system without root access and restriction on what i can install.

Comment: Since `top` is a graphical program, it's trying to display things on the connected TTY - which in this case does no longer exist. Use something else than `top` for testing.

Comment: LoganLee if the system is restricted, and you need a service that's best provided by a well-known tool such as `screen`, make an appropriate application for that tool to be installed